# cannot inflate floating action button

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
             android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_av_videocam_white"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/primaryColor"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Style.xml code:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/CustomDialog</item>
    <!--<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>-->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base.FullScreen" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/grey_100</item>-->
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Gradle File:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

dexOptions {
    jumboMode true
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "in.co.memoize"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 14
    versionName "1.13"

    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
```

Getting the error "the following class could not be instantiated: 
android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton"

Stack Trace:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.(Landroid/widget/ImageView;Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatDrawableManager;)V
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:133)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:176)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:229)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:519)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I have tried all the recommendations from the previous questions. Nothing seem to fix this.. Please help..

Comment: could you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: that must be showing in layout preview only. You will see your button when you run your app.

Comment: the app is crashing :

Comment: @VivekMishra: the app is crashing with error: Binary XML file: error inflating class com.android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Comment: @MerveSahin: I have edited the question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Are you using release buildType? You might be enabled proguard with restrict rules. Can you also send your proguard?

Comment: There would be also problem with multidex.

Comment: Solved it by updating to latest sdk tool.